# bold cell based on specific value in column J

Tags: excel, vba

I already tried using this code and its not working

```
Sub Bold()
 With Sheets("1470")
        For Each Cell In Range("J:J")
            If Cell.Value = "N/A" Then
                Cell.Font.bold = True
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

the output that I want to execute is every cell in column J that contains "N/A" gets bold

I got error

> "Type mismatch"

Comment: Which line causes the error?  I pasted your code into a new module, stepped through it and it set my "N/A" values to a bold font with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Hi GoodJuju, i got error on this line:

If rCell.Value = "N/A" Then

Comment: @MR.BLANK "Conditional Formatting" is your friend. Have a look for it, this can be completely done without VBA, so it gets formatted instantly whenever an error occurs (without a need to run the macro again).

Comment: @Peh, thats the recommended way to do, but my concern is using this conditional formatting cause increase a file size?

Comment: What output do you get if you put a `Debug.Print cell.Value` on the next line, following your 'For...' statement?  Does it return "N/A".

Comment: Did you mean to type rCell.Value in your comment or Cell.Value?  rCell.Value is not in your code.

Comment: "object required"

Comment: @MR.BLANK check my answer - it should solve your issue.

Comment: Is this the only excel file you have open and is the sheet definitely selected and active?  From your comments it looks like it may not be getting the right sheet and is not finding the cell range.

Comment: when using a `With`-Block you want to referenz `Ranges` with `.Range(J:J)`

Comment: Is the contents the **string** `N/A` or is it the error value `#NA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption you looking for `#N/A` errors on your worksheet caused by the same formulas in that column.

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1470")
    Set rng1 = .Range("J1:J" & .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If .Evaluate("=SUM(--ISNA(" & rng1.Address & "))") > 0 Then
        Set rng2 = Intersect(rng1, rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors))
        rng2.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use `J:J` It will slow your code. Find the last row and then check in that range.
2. To specifically check for `#N/A` use `CVErr()` as shown below.
3. If you want to check for any error then go with `IsError()` as mentoned by @PawelCzyz.

Is this what you are trying?

```
With Sheets("1470")
    lrow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Range("J1:J" & lrow)
        If CVErr(cell.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
            cell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: Right what I had in mind :). I was also thinking about `.Intersect` on specialcells `XlSpecialCellsValue` with `xlErrors` as it's most likely the only errors in a same column would be the `#N/A`. Then again, OP might have meant textual `N/A`.

Comment: Textual "N/A" will not give `Type mismatch` so I am sure the OP is trying to catch actual #N/A error. But then I could be wrong :D